# mssql select count from 2 tables

Tags: sql-server

There are 2 tables

```
Checklist_top
Checklist_body
```

related the field IDcheckTop

```
Checklist_top
ID,Facility
1, Item1
2, Item2
3, Item3
4, Item4
5, Item5
6, Item6
7, Item1

Checklist_body
ID, IDcheckTop, Answer
1,      1,        0
2,      1,        0
3,      2,        1
4,      2,        0
5,      3,        0
6,      3,        0
7,      4,        1
8,      4,        1
9,      5,        1
10,     5,        0
11,     6,        0
12,     6,        1 
13,     7,        1
14,     7,        0
```

You want to write a query that calculates the number of columns in this

```
Facility, TOTAL, COUNT_1
Item1,      2,     1
Item2,      1,     1
Item3,      1,     0 
Item4,      1,     1
Item5,      1,     1
Item6,      1,     1
Item7,      1,     1
```

Comment: What is COUNT_1 column represents?

Comment: What is Total and Count_1 - its not matching with the data set that you have provided.

Comment: `COUNT_1` for `Item4` = 1 or 2?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query

```
SELECT
  t.Facility,
  COUNT(DISTINCT t.ID) TOTAL,
  ISNULL(SUM(b.Answer),0) COUNT_1
FROM Checklist_top t
LEFT JOIN Checklist_body b ON b.IDcheckTop=t.ID
GROUP BY t.Facility
```

Comment: Leran2002 Thank you very much! :-)